# Link image from imgur

Tags: support, images

I uploaded an image to imgur (https://i.stack.imgur.com/obXEE.jpg)

Now I try to insert that image in an answer, like this one, but it doesn't work. I click insert an image, from web, then I paste the exact same url in the box and I get "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported".

Is this expected behavior? I would expect that I could link existing images from imgur

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must use the image form:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZJIX.png

Not the page which has the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/obXEE.jpg

[image]

---

For future reference, you can use this to easily add an image:

```
![][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZJIX.png
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a way anymore to get Imgur to automatically display the direct link, like in the image above. Is there still a way to do this, or do I need to guess the file type and enter `.png` manually?

Comment: @incandescentman any file type will work, imgur is smart enough to serve the image as-is even with a wrong extension. e.g. [this](http://i.imgur.com/FPyso27.gif) will serve the original picture, with `image/png` Content Type header.

Answer (score 4):

The link is only a page containing the image. It's an HTML file. You need the *actual* image link:

```
http://i.imgur.com/FPyso27.png
```